# AppServiceProvider creates problems during import

Tags: laravel, middleware

I have in my AppServiceProvider code, which generates menu from MenuTop model.

```
class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider

{

    public function boot()
    {

        $topmenu =  MenuTop::wherePublished(true)
                            ->get()
                            ->toTree()
                            ->toArray();

        View::share('topmenu', $topmenu);

    }
```

All is OK except one problem. In backend I have import controller from XLS to database and functions in AppServiceProvider creates problems during import. Sometimes import is not possible until I completely comment `boot()`.
Is there a way to fix that? Maybe it is possible to move that code from AppServiceProvider to Middleware and assign that only to `public` routes, not to `admin` routes?

Comment: "functions in AppServiceProvider creates problems during import" what kind of problems?

Comment: Import of Menutop model from XLS into DB in admin is not possible until the the code in AppServiceProvider is not commented. It always gives me errors during import. I think that this because before import model is truncated and then AppServiceProvider is trying to get it. So when I need to import data in DB I always comment AppServiceProvider before.